# Class-based Message System Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-method

I'm trying to create an extensible system for building messages.

I want each style of message to be a unique class. I don't want the client to have to worry about the class type when creating the message (or reading it – but that is not included here).

In the code below, I only use *ints* and *Strings*. The final version would wrap *ints* and *Strings* in another class with data validation if necessary.

```
// Run from main
import xx.xxx.StandardFactory.*;
private void standardFactoryTest() {
    StandardFactory standardFactory = new StandardFactory();

    BasePackage testPackage1 = standardFactory.makePackage("Text for One");
    BasePackage testPackage2 = standardFactory.makePackage(999);
    BasePackage testPackage3 = standardFactory.makePackage("Text for Three", 129);

    testPackage1.printData(); // prints “StringPackage value: Text for One”
    testPackage2.printData(); // prints “IntPackage value: 999”
    testPackage3.printData(); // prints “StringIntPackage value: Text for Three, 129”
}

package xx.xxx.StandardFactory;

public class StandardFactory {
    public abstract class BasePackage{
        public abstract void printData();
    }

    public class StringPackage extends BasePackage {
        private final String value;

        StringPackage(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void printData() {
            System.out.println("StringPackage value: " + value);
        };
    }

    public class IntPackage extends BasePackage  {
        private final int value;

        IntPackage(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void printData() {
            System.out.println("IntPackage value: " + value);
        };
    }

    public class StringIntPackage extends BasePackage  {
        private final String stringValue;
        private final int intValue;

        StringIntPackage(String stringValue, int intValue) {
            this.stringValue = stringValue;
            this.intValue = intValue;
        }

        public void printData() {
            System.out.println("StringIntPackage value: " + stringValue + ", " + intValue);
        };
    }

    public StringPackage makePackage(String value) {
        return new StringPackage(value);
    }

    public IntPackage makePackage(int value) {
        return new IntPackage(value);
    }

    public StringIntPackage makePackage(String stringValue, int intValue) {
        return new StringIntPackage(stringValue, intValue);
    }
}
```

**Potential problems:**
    If I add new classes I need to add them to the factory. I don't see this as too much work.
    Messages could take arguments in a different order. I will not need to make every different     combination of input for my purposes so this should not be a problem.
    Large packages may need five or six different arguments. This goes against the principle of     using few arguments in a function, but it would be the exception not the rule.

**I am interested specifically in the following:**

1. Is this a common design
   pattern (is it a version of the factory pattern)?
2. Are there more
   suitable design pattern options available?
3. Are there any obvious
   improvements?
4. Is it possible to have the factory static so I don't
   need a factory object?

**I am not interested in the following (with reasons):**

1. Naming – This has been done as example code
2. Comments – I have not attempted to comment this code
3. Data validation – Not required at this point

Everything else is fair game.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are on the right way. But mostly depends how will the client use your factory and `BasePackage`.
Here are some my minor remarks for improvements:

- Only `BasePackage` is to be public, all the implementation classes are to be hidden.
- `makePackage()` should return `BasePackage` type.
- To reduce possible 5..6 arguments think about varargs solution.
- Yes, you may have factory as a static, because you don't have an internal state (at least for now).
- Naming: if possible rename `BasePackage` to reflect your domain area. `BasePackage` for client perspective may be not clear. But it is ok if you have good package hierarchy.

Comment: Great ideas. I'll look into those. Thank you.

Comment: I really like the idea of having BasePackage public and keeping the rest private. There is no need for the client to know the message type. Varargs is a good idea, but I will enclose all primatives in other classes so I don't need to worry about that. I will set everything static (including the different XXXPackages). Names will be altered. Thank you for all your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You mention extesibility as a goal of the project. You might consider making BasePackage an *interface* rather than a base class, and using composition, rather than extension to create the `StringPackage` `IntPackage` and `StringIntPackage` classes. That will give you *much* more freedom in how those classes (and future classes) are implemented.

I don't think this would change much at present. But as more XxxPackage classes are added, and more features are added, that flexibilty becomes simultaneously more important, and harder to add.

I also don't see a need to make `StringPackage`, `IntPackage`, and `StringIntPackag` member classes of `StandardFactory`. As more Package implementations are added, this code will get harder and harder to read & maintain. I suggest making them independent classes. If you're concerned about outside packages instantiating them directly, you can make the classes package-private, and only expose the `BasePackage` as public.

(Sidenote: there's a larger anti-pattern at work here. Any time a single file is the "right place" for lots of future changes/additions, you're setting yourself up for trouble. I only use member classes when instances need to access the internals of the parent class.)

I think your instincts are right about replacing the StandardFactory instance with a static factory method. I don't see a need here (though this is a simplified example) for

With all that done, here's the new code (note that it's split into 5 separate files):

```
/* file: StandardFactory.java */
package xx.xxx;// Run from main

/**
 * Provides static factory methods for Package instances.
 */
public class StandardFactory
{
    public StringPackage makePackage(String value) {
        return new StringPackage(value);
    }

    public IntPackage makePackage(int value) {
        return new IntPackage(value);
    }

    public StringIntPackage makePackage(String stringValue, int intValue) {
        return new StringIntPackage(stringValue, intValue);
    }
}

/* file: Package.java */
package xx.xxx;

public interface Package
{
    void printData();
}

/* file: IntPackage.java */
package xx.xxx;

class IntPackage implements Package
{
    private final int value;

    IntPackage(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("IntPackage value: " + value);
    }
}

/* file: StringPackage.java */
package xx.xxx;

class StringPackage implements Package
{
    private final String value;

    StringPackage(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("StringPackage value: " + value);
    }
}

/* file: StringIntPackage.java */
package xx.xxx;

class StringIntPackage implements Package
{
    private final String stringValue;
    private final int intValue;

    StringIntPackage(String stringValue, int intValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("StringIntPackage value: " + stringValue + ", " + intValue);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Chis Definitely helps. I need to spend some time thining about this before I can ask the questions I want to a

Comment: @David, Glad to hear it's helpful! No solution is perfect, least of all mine. But I hope it gives you food for thought. Cheers!

Comment: @Chis I considered a separate class for each Package, but decided to put them into a single 'Packages' class to keep everything in one place. I looked at using an Interface, but it seemed wrong. The extensions of Package are logical extensions of the class, and I would like to have some other functions in the base that will be shared by descendants. Any flaws with these choices?

Comment: @David Generally, if your goal is extensibility (as you mentioned in your original question), using an interface and separate classes will serve that purpose better than a base class & inheritance. Using internal classes also works against extensibility. I *totally* agree with your instinct to provide a clear place for new code to go, but in my own code I avoid having that place be in a single *file*. It encourages merge conflicts and makes that file less readable.